# I am trying to copy rowlabels of 4 pivottables one after another to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to copy 4 pivot row labels data to another sheet called "RSL to Review" one after other pivot row label data. I am able to copy only one pivot data that too whole data and no error after that no loop works.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer

    For i = 1 To 4
        LR = Sheets("pivot").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

       ' Sheets("RSL to Review").Activate

        Sheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable" & i).PivotSelect "", xlLabel,true 
            Selection.Copy
        Sheets("RSL to Review").Activate
            Sheets("RSL to Review").Range("b" & LR + 2).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
End Sub
```

Result should be platform (pivot row label)

```
Region  Platform
APJ Barit/Bucci
APJ Cannonball 1.0
APJ EvansDG
```

Comment: Could it be because you are using `Select`? This is not necessary to copy/paste things. `Selection.Copy Sheets("RSL to Review").Range("b" & LR + 2)` should also work.

Comment: if i use selection.copy gives error .

Comment: Do I have to guess the error? :)

Comment: Object doesnt support thisproperty or method

Comment: Have you put my suggested code in one line or is it on two lines? I would expect this error if you put it on two lines. It should be on one.

Comment: Sheets("RSL to Review").Range("b" & LR + 2).Selection.Copy

Comment: That's not what I wrote :). `Selection.Copy Sheets("RSL to Review").Range("b" & LR + 2)` on the place where you now only used `Selection.copy` and you can get rid of the three lines below.

Comment: :(we cant make this change for the selected cells
because it will affect a ivot table.
use the field list to change the report .if you are 
trying to insert or delete cells ,move the pivot table and 
try again- error

Comment: im not understanding as we are making changes in the worksheet where we dont have pivot table why is this error coming Alex

Comment: I don't follow you I'm sorry. If you can't use my suggestion, then I don't know. It doesn't delete anything, it just prevents you from activating another sheet. Other than that it should do the same as your current code.

Comment: i used your suggestion and it gave the above error which i had mentioned. this is the error which i got "we cant make this change for the selected cells because it will affect a pivot table. use the field list to change the report .if you are trying to insert or delete cells ,move the pivot table and try again"

Comment: it run time error 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter "Mode" for `PivotTable.PivotSelect` has to be `xlLabelOnly` and not "xlLabel" (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlptselectionmode)).

Your calculation of the last used row ("LR") has to be performed on the *destination* sheet - and *directly before each* paste operation.

Please try this first:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer

    Sheets("pivot").Activate
    For i = 1 To 4
        Sheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable" & i).PivotSelect "", xlLabelOnly, True
        Selection.Copy

        With Sheets("RSL to Review")
            LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(LR + 2, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

You may change the `Range.PasteSpecial` parameter [Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) to `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` or whatever needed. If you paste `xlPasteAll` or `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` you also have pivottables at the destination (and an error, if they would overlap each other).

---

As you work with `PivotSelect` to copy the *selected range*, that sheet *must* be active (activated) before. As everybody tries to [avoid selecting or activating anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/10908769), there is a better solution.

You can copy `RowFields().LabelRange` or `RowFields().DataRange` (or both by `Union`) by this without selecting or activating anything:

```
Sub CopyPivotRowlabels()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LR As Long

    For i = 1 To 4
        With Sheets("pivot").PivotTables(i).RowFields(1)
            .DataRange.Copy
            'Union(.LabelRange, .DataRange).Copy
        End With

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RSL to Review")
            LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(LR + 2, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```